# Default value in struct field when instance it

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I've just started to learn C++.

I have this `struct`:

```
struct dateTime
{
    int sec;
    int min;
    int hour;
    int day;
    int mon;
    int year;
    bool daylightSaving;
    char timeZone;
};
```

And I need to set `daylightSaving` to false by default.

How can I do it? Maybe I have to use a class instead of a `struct`.

Comment: Add constructor `dateTime() : daylightSaving ( false ) {}`

Comment: struct and class are the same thing in c++, just different defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write for example

```
struct dateTime
{
    int sec;
    int min;
    int hour;
    int day;
    int mon;
    int year;
    bool daylightSaving = false;
    char timeZone;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So you say in C++, what about having a default constructor initializing all values?

```
struct dateTime
{
 dateTime()
 : sec(0)
 , min(0)
 , hour(0)
 , day(0)
 , mon(0)
 , year(0)
 , daylightSaving(false)
 , timeZone('a') //Are you sure you just want one character? time zones have multiple... UTC GMT ...
 {}

...
}
```

You can use a class instead, but the difference is only that all values are private by default. So you need

```
class ...
{
   public:
   ...
}
```

to have the same behavior as with the struct.

Comment: I’m using a char to store a value between-127 and 127 (forget the unsigned, is a mistake).